# Socket IO Event Handler in componentDidMount/componentDidUpdate React JS

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, event-handling, react-dom

I have a socket io event handler that is receiving data every second. On page load, how to call componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate inside the event handler?

Or is there another way that the event handler being call inside componentDidMount or componentDidUpdate?

I don't know how to link the event handler with the lifecycle in react js (so the graph will be updated everytime a new data enters the eventhandler)

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = { 
  trafficFlow: [],
  cameraId: this.props.cameraId,
  cameraIp: this.props.cameraIp,
  ReceivedDateTime: '',
  QueueLength: '',
 };

 this.globals = new Globals();
 this.socketIO = new Socket_IO();
 this.socketIO.SubscribeSocket_IO = this.handleSocketIOMessage;
}

handleSocketIOMessage = (eventTitle, message) => {
var self = this;

switch (eventTitle) {
  case "trafficFlow":
    // console.log("handleSocketIOMessage: eventTitle=" + eventTitle + ", message=" + message);
    var trafficFlowParse = JSON.parse(message);
    var ReceivedDateTime = new Date(trafficFlowParse.ReceivedDateTime);
    var Time = ReceivedDateTime.getHours() +  ":" +  (ReceivedDateTime.getMinutes()<10?'0':'') + ReceivedDateTime.getMinutes();
    //var QueueLength = trafficFlowParse.QueueLength;


    trafficFlowParse.ReceivedDateTime = Time;

    self.setState({ trafficFlow: trafficFlowParse});
    console.log(this.state.trafficFlow);

    //self.setState({ Time: trafficFlowParse.Time, QueueLength: trafficFlowParse.QueueLength});
    //self.setState({ trafficFlow: Time});
    //console.log("Time : " + this.state.trafficFlow);
    //console.log("Received Date Time : " + Time);
    //console.log("Queue Length : " + QueueLength);
    break;
 }
};

componentDidMount() {
//this.handleSocketIOMessage();
}

componentDidUpdate() {

}
```

Comment: You can't. Life-cycle is used inside react `classical component`

Comment: @keikai is there a workaround to solve this?